# Eclipse or spring boot doesn't allow calling any of delete API

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot

I am using eclipse to test some small API and is strange but it doesn't allow me to call any API that deletes... I am getting this error
for this

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/users/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
 public void deleteUser(@PathVariable String id) {
      System.out.println("BLOOD HELL");
 }
```

the error >>>>
    GET "/users/3", parameters={}
    Request method 'GET' not supported: Completed 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED

I don't understand why is there a get where I
 am using delete.

> I am calling with **Http**
>   So to be clear I know that the error means I don't have a method with that path, but what I don't understand is how is possible that there is that **get** when should be **delete** somehow the eclipse or spring boot gets this info wrong

Comment: your request method is delete and you are trying to execute Via get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry i don't speak english very well i'm using google translate, try using the annotation

```
@DeleteMapping (value = /users/{id})
```

But using Postman, using the delete method

Comment: Put the code of your complete controller class for us to take a look

Comment: I have already switch in spring tools suite 4 and had no problem

Answer (score 2):

You need to call this API using DELETE request.
As posted by you, you are using GET request.
Server is not able to find the API with GET request, that's why you are getting 405 error code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test DELETE API using postman or some other tool not from browser. If you will test from browser then method will be HTTP GET not DELETE.

Comment: I HAVE TESTED AND I GET **Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens**

Answer (score 0):

You have a Delete mapping but you are accessing that API from GET.
If in Postman, choose DELETE instead of GET.

If you're accessing the API from a browser it will by default use GET so if you actually want to access this API call it from Postman and choose DELETE method.

If you're using `http`, try `https` or vice versa.

Comment: yeah i have done that but is that same thing , AND I GET Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens

Comment: Use https instead of http. I have edited the answer

Comment: yeah i am doing this, but is the same

Comment: What is the URL you're using?